# How to parse a string?

Tags: java, string, variable-length

So I'm trying to get the user to enter text into a text box and my program will tell the user how many letters the word contains. I initialized the variable String1 (`String String1;`) to be the word the user entered. Now the part I'm confused about is that when I try to set the label for the answer to display the answer I get the error

> int cannot be converted to string.

Here's the part of the code I'm stuck on:

```
String String1;

String1 = txtlength.getText();


lblLengthAnswer.setText (String1.length());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `setText()` method accepts only `Strings` (I'm not completely sure, because you only pasted part of the code, but I'm pretty sure). On the other hand String#length() gives you an int value. You can't pass int to a method which requires a String, hence the error. To call it java would need to convert an int to String, which it doesn't do. Convert the int to String by hand, by calling `String.valueOf`. And please start variable names with lowercase.